# Checkmark on the left side of Menu items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a Menu where the selected item has a checkmark.
Right now, the checkmark is on the right side::

```
Button(action: {
    self.categoryIndex = index
    self.selectedCategory = category
  }, label: {
  Text(category)
  if selectedCategory == categories[index] {
    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
  }                               
})
```

I need the checkmark on the left side, like this picture:
[image: Dropdown with checkmarks on left side of selections]
How do I achieve the selections like the photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably more ways to do this, but here are two options:

**Using a Picker**

```
    Picker("Menu", selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(1..<5, id: \.self) { number in
            Text("Option \(number)")
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

which will be displayed like this (iOS / MacOS):

[image]

---

**Using Toggles**

This is slightly more involving since you want to bind some kind of action on selections (assuming that you need a *single* selection, like above), so I don't know if it's worth the trouble, but for pedagogical reasons, here it is:

```
struct CheckedMenu: View {
    @State private var selection = "1"
    var body: some View {
        Menu("Menu") {
            Toggle("Option 1", isOn: bindingForOption("1"))
            Toggle("Option 2", isOn: bindingForOption("2"))
        }
    }
    
    private func bindingForOption(_ option: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool>(get: { selection == option }, set: { if $0 { selection = option } })
    }
}
```

which will be displayed like this (iOS / MacOS):

[image]

---

Finally, for what is worth, note that the second option (toggles) allows for *multiple* (unrelated) items to be simultaneously checked, which would be a better choice for "option" menus like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. I can not have the up/down carets with the Picker, so I will go with your toggle suggestion. How can I prevent multiple selections?

Comment: The code for toggles in my answer already handles that, provided that the binding values are distinct. You could use a `ForEach` of course instead of manually writing each row.